# Detect if user taps on url in pdf viewer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, detect, pdf-viewer

I am using vfrReader in my app as pdf viewer to display some pdf documents, and the problem is there are some urls or email links in those document, I would like allow user to tap on url to  open web browser or email link to open email composer like in UIWebView.

Does anyone know how to do this please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using iOS' Document Interaction Controller to view the PDF? I guess It would allow you to open links like that. Though im not sure, But as far as i understand it must be the Readers capability to distinguish hypertext from plain text.

Comment: Thanks Apple_iOS0304, I will give this a try.

Comment: you are most welcome.. since its apple's own documents reader for iOS, it renders quite many thing automatically..